# intBitsToFloat counterpart: floatToIntBits or floatToRawIntBits?

Tags: java, android, floating-point

In a very specific task, I am forced to store a `float` in an `int` variable (which will be persisted later, and then read back). All operations are done as `float`, i.e. a possible scenario is as follows:

1. Calculate the `float` value, and work with it
2. Store it as an `int`
3. Later, read the `int`, and convert it to `float` immediately
4. Work with the `float` value again

That is, `int` is purely a *storage* format. I was thinking of using `intBitsToFloat` to regain my `float` value. In this case, which is the proper method for exporting the `float` value? `floatToIntBits()` or `floatToRawIntBits()`? I can't find it in the javadoc or anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find it in the Android source code. The appropriate counterpart of `intBitsToFloat()` is `floatToRawIntBits()`. Their C source code is as follows:

```
static jint floatToRawBits(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, jfloat val)
{
    Float   f;
    f.f = val;
    return f.bits;
}

static jfloat intBitsToFloat(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, jint val)
{
    Float   f;
    f.bits = val;
    return f.f;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually the difference in these two methods is well described in Float API, these methods produce different results only for NaN but both results are valid and for your task you can use any of them. NaN may have many representations `s111 1111 1axx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx`, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN. floatToIntBits always returns `0111 1111 1100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` for NaN while floatToInt returns NaN binary representation as is.

Comment: For this particular situation, I would use floatToRawIntBits. It reproduces the float. floatToIntBits seems better if you are going to process the resulting int and want a quick test for it being a NaN.

Comment: Of course the difference between the two methods is described well in the API. But that wasn't my question, and didn't give any information for answering it (i.e. which is needed to get a format reversible by intToFloatBits). The Android source code answered the question. But thanks for the interesting and useful comments, of course.

Comment: Actually the difference is not very well described in the API. You have to compare the two lengthy method descriptions line by line.